# defining an appropriate variable name

Tags: python, types, keyword

How can i catch this very basic error before it occurs ?

```
# create a variable
str = 10
print(str)
print(type(str))

# change from integer to string
str = str(str)
print(str)
```

The error is:

```
'int' object is not callable
```

I would assert that `str` is a keyword and a standard linter should pick this up, but my linter does not because `str` is in fact **not** a keyword (https://realpython.com/lessons/reserved-keywords/).

The same is true for int, list etc.

So how to catch or prevent this error before it occurs ?

Comment: A good [type checker](http://mypy-lang.org/) will catch things like this.

Comment: i have `mypy` and `pylint` enabled in `vscode` and neither picked this up... does this flag to you as an error in your editor ?

Comment: Yes it does. I just copy-pasted the code in this question into a new file and ran `mypy filename.py` (with no additional configuration options). It gave me one error, about `int` not being callable.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo , was this at run time or before running the code ?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Which version of `mypy` are you using? 0.930 doesn't catch `str = 10`, even with `--strict`.

Comment: @chepner Running 0.800. `str = 10` is fine, but `str = str(str)` is the line mypy catches for me.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Ah, OK. It would be nice if `str` were typed in a way that at least limits what could be assigned to it. (Say, `Callable[..., str]`)

Comment: how are you invoking `strict` ?  Do you just type strict at the top of the code - `python` does not seem to have a strict mode like, for example, javascript...

Comment: @chepner You're not assigning to `builtins.str` (which has a well-defined type that's probably something like `Callable[[any], str]`). You're shadowing it with a module-level variable in your own module. That's why mypy doesn't mind.

Comment: Oh, right; scope matters.

Answer (score 0):

The `str` you are using is a function in python. So when you are assigning `str` a value, you have overridden the function address stored in `str` with some value. So the `str` is no more a function. So when you tried to call str() it returned the error.

Look at the below output for better understanding.

```
>>> str(123)
'123'

>>> str = 4

>>> str(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

This output is from python command line interpreter. Hope this helped.

Comment: That's the error the OP wants to catch *before* runtime.

Comment: Agreed, this is what i get (at runtime tho). What i am trying to understand is why a user is allowed to overwrite a "keyword" in the first instance. Or at least why the words `int`, `str`, `list`, `dict` are not reserved in the same way as the 33 known `keywords` ?

Comment: Keywords are for the benefit of the parser, not an error-checking mechanism. Despite the attitudes some people around here, I don't see a problem with reusing a built-in name in a *limited* scope when you don't need the previously bound value.

Comment: Also, if `str` really were a keyword, then you couldn't use it as an attribute name, where there is *no* chance of shadowing a built-in name.

Comment: Well, as far as i know, since everything in python is an object, as it is a object oriented language. So the int(), or str() are basically static classes, so the names can be overridden with another value, but if we delete the overridden value the previous charecteristics for the variable will be resurrected to it. As the IDE's uses systax highlighters, they can be used to find the inbuilt functions or classes.

Comment: `str` is a built-in function, when you type `str(object)` you are actually returning `object.__str__()`, but you can change this behavior if you change the encoding or the errors. As said above, keywords are not an error-checking mechanism.

Comment: @chepner,  i take on board the first comment and in fact i can use `del str` to reveal the `str()` function, but can you please explain your second comment as a code example ?

Comment: @AugustoOliveira : this makes sense.